# Kicked out of backend "Visible section not found."

Tags: magento2, admin-login

Magento 2.2 is allowing me to login to the backend, but as soon as I click on something it sends me back to the login form and shows the message

> Visible section not found.

I don't see any errors in Apache's log, and there are no errors in any of Magento's `var/log/*.log` files.

I have manually removed Magento cache files. Also tried clearing the session table in the database and ran `bin/magento setup:upgrade` in verbose mode.

I have also run: `bin/magento cache:flush`  and `bin/magento cache:clean`

What other steps can I take to troubleshoot this?

Update:
I have found that this is caused by a module I used to help with the development process. However, it was basically just from turning modules on and off and testing each one.  There was NO indication in any log file of the cause.  Would still love to see suggestions on where I could have found this.

Comment: Clear your cache and try to login again.

Comment: @Cyclonecode my browser cache? I did that... and tried another browser, and had a colleague try from their machine.

Comment: No not the browser cache the magento cache =) You should be able to do this from the command line by going to your magento root directory and execute: `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: @Cyclonecode yeah, did this too. I just updated my question to include that note.

Comment: If your site isn't live you can try to turn on error messages by coping `pub/errors/local.xml.sample` to `pub/errors/local.xml` and clean your cache. The log files should then be found under the  `var/log` directory. Oops didn't noticed that you already tried this.

Comment: Which module was this?

Comment: @Cyclonecode I am not sure I can fully blame the module, but disabling it made this stop happening. MSP DevTools. This could have been something specific to my install though.

Comment: I'm getting this and am not using this module. I've even disabled third party or custom modules.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to solve this problem, too.
But Solution was very easy in my case.

Go to magento_root/app/etc/ then open file env.php

Change below **frontName xxxxxx** with what you want

**return array ( 
  'backend' => array ( 
    'frontName' => 'xxxxxx', 
  ),**
.......

Comment: Somehow changing again admin FrontName , solve the problem. I think I had that issue after enabling MSP_DevTool like from comments above.

Comment: I have this issue after enabling MSP_DevTool, and changing frontName didn't help